# Dúvida sobre a versão do laravel:

Tags: php, laravel

Quando fiz a instalação do laravel  eu usei o comando: “composer global require laravel/installer"  sendo realizado a instalação da última versão que está funcionando normal. Quero criar um projeto na versão 5.1, como ficaria o comando correto? Eu tentei destas formas mais não deu certo:

1 - composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel nome-do-projeto 5.1.*

2 - laravel/laravel nome-do-projeto 5.1.*

3 - laravel nome-do-projeto 5.1.*

OBS: será que tenho que reinstalar o laravel?: se sim, como remover a versão anterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para instalar uma determinada versão [siga a documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation) e utilize o [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) como a linha de comando logo abaixo:

```
php composer create-project laravel/laravel nome_do_projeto "5.1.*"
```

como descrito na sua [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation), forçando a instalção da versão [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) `5.1`.

Comment: será que tenho que reinstalar o laravel, estou com a última versão?: se sim, como remover a versão anterior

Comment: não precisa reinstalar o `Laravel`, é só escolher o diretório para a nova instalação e fazer o uso do `composer` como descrito na resposta. Dica sempre utilize o composer para gerenciar suas apliçãções Laravel. Dessa forma a sua instalação será do Laravel 5.1

Comment: C:xampp\htdocs> composer create-project laravel/laravel nome_do_projeto "5.1.*" aparentemente deu certo